# requests in Flask return 404

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm creating my first app where it gets a response a bunch of URL's but when I run it through Flask only one URL gets <response [200]> and the rest get [404]. The function works on its own and the issue occurs only when it runs through flask.

I can see that the URL's are being passed through when using print but after the URL is printed a 404 is returned when printing the response.

URL Examples:

```
https://www.crimestoppervic.com.au/
https://lunasalon.com.au/
https://bennichomes.com.au/
```

Function:

```
def get_page_response(url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        return response
```

Flask:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = URLForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['urls'] = form.urls.data
        urls = session.get('urls', None)
        lines = set(l for l in urls.split("\n") if l)
        response_list = []
        for url in lines:
            response = get_page_response(url)
            response_list.append(response)

        return render_template('index.html', title='Homepage', form=form, response_list=response_list)
    return render_template('index.html', title='Homepage', form=form)
```

HTML template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.urls.label }}<br>
    {{ form.urls(rows='20',cols='100') }}</p><br>
    {{ form.submit() }}

    {% for x in response_list %}
        <p>{{ x }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Forms:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class URLForm(FlaskForm):
    urls = TextAreaField('URLs', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Comment: can you please print the url which you are hitting?

Comment: Can you share the value of `form.urls.data` and `lines`? Are you sure that the `urls.split("\n")` results in valid URLs?

Comment: I have added the urls and the value's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else has the same issue, the answer was to remove \r character within the list.

```
lines = set(l for l in urls.split("\n") if l)
print(lines) #this will show you that inside the list items have \r

lines = [i.replace("\r", "") for i in lines] #remove \r from each item
```